# Python pomegranate package UnboundLocalError: local variable 'distributions' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x, hidden-markov-models

Please help me troubleshoot the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "hmmTest/textseq.py", line 5, in <module>
    hmm = HiddenMarkovModel.from_samples(distribution = dataDist2, n_components = 5, X = data)
  File "pomegranate/hmm.pyx", line 3738, in pomegranate.hmm.HiddenMarkovModel.from_samples
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'distributions' referenced before assignment
```

which I encounter when I run the following code:

```
from pomegranate import * 
import numpy as np 
data = [[1, 0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1, 0, 1], [1, 0, 1, 0, 0], [1, 1, 0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 1, 1, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
dataDist2 = DirichletDistribution.from_samples(np.array(data))
hmm = HiddenMarkovModel.from_samples(distribution = dataDist2, n_components = 5, X = data)
```

Please note that I get the same error even if I use a different distribution, for example, a `ConditionalProbabilityDistribution` learned from samples (I printed it out to make sure there was no error in creating the distribution).

I'm using Python 3.7.1 on macOS Mojave Version 10.14.1, and my pomegranate version is 0.11.0

Comment: The name `distributions` is supposed to be set somewhere [here](https://github.com/jmschrei/pomegranate/blob/master/pomegranate/hmm.pyx#L3673-L3728), but apparently you've found a path where it never gets assigned. I see there was a [change made a few days ago](https://github.com/jmschrei/pomegranate/pull/551/commits/5cd411cba21fe52830608040a1662c520ffcd4c5#diff-16503312cc32dfb87898df1d62fd1d8bR3708) to that code; maybe that fixes it?

Comment: I used `pip3 install pomegranate -U` to get the latest version (0.11.0) of the package before I ran the script. I suspected I might have found a path where it never gets assigned, and so I emailed the authors about it. If I get an answer from them, I will post it here. Thanks! (You didn't downvote the question, did you? If you did, please let me know why.)

Comment: I did not; presumably, the downvote is from someone who thought the error was triggered by your own code.